# Cannot assign '1': Comment.user must be a user instance

Tags: django

... But it is!? I'm using Django 1.9 and Python 3.

I'm trying to let people comment on a post, my model looks like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, unique=False)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=450)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    edited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    replies = models.ManyToManyField('Comment', blank=True)
    score = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

I'm not using a form, instead I am trying to create the object in the view:

```
def PostView(request, user, slug):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, user__username=user, slug=slug)
    context = {
        'object': instance,
        'MEDIA_URL': MEDIA_URL,
        'STATIC_URL': STATIC_URL
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':

        data_type = request.POST.get('type')

        if data_type == 'comment':
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            author = get_user(request)
            author_id = author.id
            post = instance
            comment = Comment(user=author_id, post=post, content=content)
```

However this should work fine, but I get this really strange error when trying to POST a comment:

> Cannot assign "1": "Comment.user" must be a "User" instance.

The error occurs when I'm trying to create the object. [Full traceback can be seen here](http://dpaste.com/0V1EXGN)

Comment: `author_id` is not a `User`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should assign a `User` to the `Comment.user` field. You are currently assigning the id instead. You can either do:

```
comment = Comment(user=author, post=post, content=content)
```

or

```
comment = Comment(user_id=author_id, post=post, content=content)
```

Comment: Whoa, that is really strange. This is the first thing I tried, and I got an error then, but when trying it again it seems to magically work now. Django must be 4th dimensional just like an USB.